# My PHP MYSQL query doesn't return all results in HTML - Full historical record of gig table contents needs to be shown, only showing partial

Tags: php, mysql

**The problem**

I have a historical gigs tab that I am adding to a page connecting to a gig database and have a MySQL query within it that is designed to grab all gigs on the database that started earlier than 2 hours ago.

This is to allow ongoing gigs to appear for 2 hours after their start time in the upcoming gigs tab so that people can still see entries for ongoing gigs when they go to see what's upcoming.

The historical gigs tab should show the full history of gigs stored on the site, going back to the first ever gig.

I have tested the query directly on the database through phpmyadmin and it has run correctly. Showing me all historical gig entries going back to the start of the table.

However, when I come to run the query on the php page I am working in it doesn't show all of the database entries on the gig table. It seems to omit the most recent day of gigs entirely, even though they all appear on the phpmyadmin sql query test.

Can someone please enlighten me as to what silly mistake I am making when trying to output the whole history of gig entries through the PHP code below?

*NB: Left joins are used throughout query as I want to show ALL gigs, even if some foreign key connections are NULL on other tables.*

**The code**

```
<div id="HistoricalGigs" class="tabcontent">
<br><br>
<?php 

$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT gig.id AS gigid, gig.artist_id, gig.gig_date, gig.gigname, artist.artistname, artist.profileimgURL, gig.venue_id, gig.stage_id, venue.venuename, festival.festivalid AS festivalid, festival.festivalname, stage.stageid AS stageid, stage.stagename, events.id AS eventid, events.eventname
from gig 
left join venue
on gig.venue_id = venue.id
left join artist
on gig.artist_id = artist.id
left join events
on gig.event_id = events.id
left join festival
on gig.festival_id = festival.festivalid
left join stage
on gig.stage_id = stage.stageid
WHERE gig.gig_date <= NOW() - INTERVAL 2 hour
order by gig.gig_date desc");
  $stmt->execute();
  $result = $stmt-> fetchAll();
  
  if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0) { 
    
  $currentboxid = 0;
  
  foreach ($result as $row) {
        
        $gigdate =  $row["gig_date"];
        $ukgigdate = date("l, d F Y - g:i A", strtotime($gigdate));
        $eventid = $row["eventid"];
        $currentboxid = $currentboxid + 1
        
        ?>
        <html>
        <div id="gigboxforanimate<?php echo $currentboxid;?>" class="hidden">
        <?php if ($eventid > 0) { ?>
        <p class="gigbox">
        <?php } else if ($row["festivalid"] > 0){?>
        <p class="gigboxfestival">
        <?php } else echo '<p class="gigboxblue">';?>   
        <a href="/gigdetail.php?gigid=<?php echo $row["gigid"];?>" class="gigdatesstyled"><?php echo $ukgigdate;?></a> <br><br>
        
        <strong><a href="/gigdetail.php?gigid=<?php echo $row["gigid"];?>" class="gignamesstyled"><?php echo $row["gigname"];?></a></strong><br><br>
    
    <?php   
         if (empty($row["profileimgURL"])) { 
         
    $profilepic = '/images/artistdetailprofileimages/placeholder.svg';
    $artistname = $row["artistname"];

echo '<a href="/gigdetail.php?gigid='.$row["gigid"].'"> <img srcset="'.$profilepic.' 200w,  
                   '.$profilepic.' 500w"
               sizes="(max-width: 500px) 200px,
                      500px"
               src="'.$profilepic.'" alt="'.$artistname.'"></a><br><br>';
               
} else {
    
    $profilepic = $row["profileimgURL"];
    $artistname = $row["artistname"];

echo '<a href="/gigdetail.php?gigid='.$row["gigid"].'"> <img srcset="'.$profilepic.' 250w,  
                   '.$profilepic.' 500w"
               sizes="(max-width: 500px) 250px,
                      500px"
               src="'.$profilepic.'" alt="'.$artistname.'"></a><br><br>';

}   
        ?>
        

                
        <a href="/artistdetail.php?artistid=<?php echo $row["artist_id"];?>" class="artiststyled"><?php echo $row["artistname"];?></a><br>
        
        <?php if ($row["venue_id"] > 0){?>

        <a href="/venuedetail.php?venueid=<?php echo $row["venue_id"];?>" class="venuestyled"><?php echo $row["venuename"]. "<br>";?></a>
        
        <?php } else if ($row["festivalid"] > 0){?>
        
        <a href="/festivaldetail.php?festivalid=<?php echo $row["festivalid"];?>" class="festivalstyled"><?php echo $row["festivalname"]. "<br>";?></a>
        
        <?php } else echo '';?>     
    
    <?php if ($eventid > 0) {
        ?>
        <br><strong>Played as a part of: <a href="/eventdetail.php?eventid=<?php echo $eventid;?>" class="eventnamessmallstyled"><?php echo $row["eventname"];?></a></strong><?php 
        } else echo '' ?>
        
        <?php if ($row["stageid"] > 0){?>
        
        <br><br><strong>Played on stage: <a href="/stagedetail.php?stageid=<?php echo $row["stageid"];?>" class="festivalnamessmallstyled"><?php echo $row["stagename"];?></a></strong><br>
        
        <?php } else echo '';?>
                
        <html></p><br>
        <center>.- - ... ..- ... -. .. .-.-.- -.-. --- --</center><br>
        </div>
        </html>
        
        <script>

$(function() {
    
    $('#gigboxforanimate<?php echo $currentboxid; ?>').slideDown(1000);
    
});
</script>
        
        <?php 
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}

?>
</div>
```

Comment: Also, I know I am using a prepared statement even though no variables are being passed to the query. I have just developed always using prepared statements as a general habit.

Comment: Does the sample PHP http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b51640cd78b9f430b7bdf6acd76a69df8ee94f26 

And rendered fiddle help or match your output?  https://jsfiddle.net/7sh5po4w/

It appears you need to delete the `<html>` tag in foreach loop, and include jQuery if not already, in your main `<head>` tag section

Comment: I actually have the starting html and closing html tags in the header and footer of the site on this page. I have simply neglected to remove them from a time when I hadn't done this yet. I also call an installed copy of jQuery min on my server in the header to be used site wide. The issue doesn't appear to be with the rending of my html code, as it all looks proper and animates well. The issue seems only to be with the actual results that appear. I will remove the extraneous html tags though, my bad.

Comment: My query gives all desired results when run directly on the database in phpmyadmin. It only doesn't give all results when run on the actual site to render.

Comment: What does count($result) output compared to the query record count from the executed query from phpmyadmin?

Comment: Well this is odd. I added a print_r function to the page and it showed that the query IS getting all of the results into the array. I then did an echo alongside each row in the foreach loop and it had the total number of results counted matching the results in phpmyadmin, BUT the first 3 counted results in the loop (i.e. the 3 most recent gigs) didn't have their corresponding html output... This boggles the mind.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/mz7greqL/1/ for a dump of what the array looks like start to finish, followed by the count loop. Which shows that the first 3 results in the loop didn't render out the html, but the following ones did. I have just gone up to gig number six in the showing of the output in the loop, and I have omitted all the actual graphical elements of the loop results and just copied in the text it renders out. However, it should work as a good example of what is actually happening here. The first 3 results are available and in the array. They just aren't output to the loop, very strange.

Comment: If still problematic check any rendering conditions that rely upon fields of a row.  If present examine the values for the issue.

Answer (score 0):

**Suggestion to solution**

If you run a `var_dump()` instead of `print_r()` and wrap the result in a preformatted tag in html like so,
`<pre><?php var_dump($array); ?></pre>`  you should be able to more easily compare the JSON result desired with the existing array contents.   Compare the first records as desired, which were incorrect and localize the value in the array to see where it is incorrectly formatted or presented.

**Solution Generated:**

After inserting the JSON provided in the fiddle JavaScript section put in for only reference, see html output and JSON - not actually used in rendering at (https://jsfiddle.net/r0nL8h36/3/)

The fiddle shows successful rendering of the missing records from the JSON dataset converted subsequently to a PHP array.

Convert the JSON from the fiddle into a valid PHP array, as the JSON from the fiddle link is valid currently.  There are probably issues in the array field value validity for interpretation by the logic.  However, running the code with the JSON produced the desired result.

**PHP Snippet with empty result set - paste the converted result of the JSON to a php array into the php snippet and run to generate the resulting html.**

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/5b44d09e962eab381dc8a931b98ffa689e4c02c1

**JSON snippet of the result set in answer fiddle**

```
  {
    "0":{
       "gigid":"222",
       "artist_id":"17",
       "album_id":"",
       "gig_date":"2021-08-15 19:30:00",
       "gigname":"Dolbro Dan's Acoustic Sunday Session (online livestream)",
       "artistname":"Dolbro Dan",
       "profileimgURL":"https://atsusni.com/images/artistdetailprofileimages/artistid-17.jpg",
       "venue_id":"268",
       "stage_id":"",
       "venuename":"Rabbit Rooms",
       "festivalid":"",
       "festivalname":"",
       "stageid":"",
       "artistname":"",
       "eventid":"",
       "eventname":""
    },
    "1":{
       "gigid":"257",
       "artist_id":"135",
       "gig_date":"2021-08-15 00:00:00",
       "gigname":"Kila",
       "artistname":"Kíla",
       "profileimgURL":"",
       "venue_id":"",
       "stage_id":"2",
       "venuename":"",
       "festivalid":"1",
       "festivalname":"Stendhal Festival",
       "stageid":"2",
       "artistname":"Karma Valley Stage",
       "eventid":"",
       "eventname":""
    },
    "2":{
       "gigid":"284",
       "artist_id":"160",
       "gig_date":"2021-08-15 00:00:00",
       "gigname":"Drew Makes Noise",
       "artistname":"Drew Makes Noise",
       "profileimgURL":"",
       "venue_id":"",
       "stage_id":"6",
       "venuename":"",
       "festivalid":"1",
       "festivalname":"Stendhal Festival",
       "stageid":"6",
       "artistname":"Henry McCullough Stage",
       "eventid":"",
       "eventname":""
    },
    "3":{
       "gigid":"278",
       "artist_id":"154",
       "gig_date":"2021-08-14 23:30:00",
       "gigname":"ferals",
       "artistname":"ferals",
       "profileimgURL":"",
       "venue_id":"",
       "stage_id":"5",
       "venuename":"",
       "festivalid":"1",
       "festivalname":"Stendhal Festival",
       "stageid":"5",
       "artistname":"Wooly Woodland Stage",
       "eventid":"",
       "eventname":""
    },
    "4":{
       "gigid":"273",
       "artist_id":"149",
       "gig_date":"2021-08-14 23:00:00",
       "gigname":"And So I Watch You From Afar",
       "artistname":"And So I Watch You From Afar",
       "profileimgURL":"",
       "venue_id":"",
       "stage_id":"1",
       "venuename":"",
       "festivalid":"1",
       "festivalname":"Stendhal Festiva",
       "stageid":"1",
       "artistname":"Stevie Martin Stage",
       "eventid":"",
       "eventname":""
    },
    "5":{
       "gigid":"285",
       "artist_id":"161",
       "gig_date":"2021-08-14 23:00:00",
       "gigname":"Queen & Disco",
       "artistname":"Queen & Disco",
       "profileimgURL":"",
       "venue_id":"",
       "stage_id":"3",
       "venuename":"",
       "festivalid":"1",
       "festivalname":"Stendhal Festival",
       "stageid":"3",
       "artistname":"Air Stage",
       "eventid":"",
       "eventname":""
    },
    "6":{
       "gigid":"277",
       "artist_id":"153",
       "gig_date":"2021-08-14 22:00:00",
       "gigname":"The Bonnevilles",
       "artistname":"The Bonnevilles",
       "profileimgURL":"",
       "venue_id":"",
       "stage_id":"5",
       "venuename":"",
       "festivalid":"1",
       "festivalname":"Stendhal Festival",
       "stageid":"5",
       "artistname":"Wooly Woodland Stage",
       "eventid":"",
       "eventname":""
    },
    "7":{
       "gigid":"283",
       "artist_id":"159",
       "gig_date":"2021-08-14 22:00:00",
       "gigname":"NewDad",
       "artistname":"NewDad",
       "profileimgURL":"",
       "venue_id":"",
       "stage_id":"6",
       "venuename":"",
       "festivalid":"1",
       "festivalname":"Stendhal Festival",
       "stageid":"6",
       "artistname":"Henry McCullough Stage",
       "eventid":"",
       "eventname":""
    },
    "8":{
       "gigid":"286",
       "artist_id":"162",
       "gig_date":"2021-08-14 22:00:00",
       "gigname":"flash Harry",
       "artistname":"flash Harry",
       "profileimgURL":"",
       "venue_id":"",
       "stage_id":"2",
       "venuename":"",
       "festivalid":"1",
       "festivalname":"Stendhal Festival",
       "stageid":"2",
       "artistname":"Karma Valley Stage",
       "eventid":"",
       "eventname":""
    },
    "9":{
       "gigid":"266",
       "artist_id":"143",
       "gig_date":"2021-08-14 21:00:00",
       "gigname":"Paddy Casey",
       "artistname":"Paddy Casey",
       "profileimgURL":"",
       "venue_id":"",
       "stage_id":"3",
       "venuename":"",
       "festivalid":"1",
       "festivalname":"Stendhal Festival",
       "stageid":"3",
       "artistname":"Air Stage",
       "eventid":"",
       "eventname":""
    },
    "10":{
       "gigid":"272",
       "artist_id":"148",
       "gig_date":"2021-08-14 21:00:00",
       "gigname":"Duke Special",
       "artistname":"Duke Special",
       "profileimgURL":"",
       "venue_id":"",
       "stage_id":"1",
       "venuename":"",
       "festivalid":"1",
       "festivalname":"Stendhal Festival",
       "stageid":"1",
       "artistname":"Stevie Martin Stage",
       "eventid":"",
       "eventname":""
    },
    "11":{
       "gigid":"276",
       "artist_id":"152",
       "gig_date":"2021-08-14 20:20:00",
       "gigname":"Kyoto Love Hotel",
       "artistname":"Kyoto Love Hotel",
       "profileimgURL":"",
       "venue_id":"",
       "stage_id":"5",
       "venuename":"",
       "festivalid":"1",
       "festivalname":"Stendhal Festival",
       "stageid":"5",
       "artistname":"Wooly Woodland Stage",
       "eventid":"",
       "eventname":""
    },
    "12":{
       "gigid":"261",
       "artist_id":"138",
       "gig_date":"2021-08-14 20:00:00",
       "gigname":"Ryan McMullan",
       "artistname":"Ryan McMullan",
       "profileimgURL":"",
       "venue_id":"",
       "stage_id":"2",
       "venuename":"",
       "festivalid":"1",
       "festivalname":"Stendhal Festival",
       "stageid":"2",
       "artistname":"Karma Valley Stage",
       "eventid":"",
       "eventname":""
    },
    "13":{
       "gigid":"265",
       "artist_id":"142",
       "gig_date":"2021-08-14 19:00:00",
       "gigname":"Susan O'Neill",
       "artistname":"Susan O’Neill",
       "profileimgURL":"",
       "venue_id":"",
       "stage_id":"3",
       "venuename":"",
       "festivalid":"1",
       "festivalname":"Stendhal Festival",
       "stageid":"3",
       "artistname":"Air Stage",
       "eventid":"",
       "eventname":""
    },
    "14":{
       "gigid":"271",
       "artist_id":"147",
       "gig_date":"2021-08-14 19:00:00",
       "gigname":"Soda Blonde",
       "artistname":"Soda Blonde",
       "profileimgURL":"",
       "venue_id":"",
       "stage_id":"1",
       "venuename":"",
       "festivalid":"1",
       "festivalname":"Stendhal Festival",
       "stageid":"1",
       "artistname":"Stevie Martin Stage",
       "eventid":"",
       "eventname":""
    },
    "15":{
       "gigid":"260",
       "artist_id":"137",
       "gig_date":"2021-08-14 18:15:00",
       "gigname":"The Henry Girls",
       "artistname":"The Henry Girls",
       "profileimgURL":"",
       "venue_id":"",
       "stage_id":"2",
       "venuename":"",
       "festivalid":"1",
       "festivalname":"Stendhal Festival",
       "stageid":"2",
       "artistname":"Karma Valley Stage",
       "eventid":"",
       "eventname":""
    },
    "16":{
       "gigid":"282",
       "artist_id":"158",
       "gig_date":"2021-08-14 18:15:00",
       "gigname":"Scála Strings",
       "artistname":"Scála Strings",
       "profileimgURL":"",
       "venue_id":"",
       "stage_id":"6",
       "venuename":"",
       "festivalid":"1",
       "festivalname":"Stendhal Festival",
       "stageid":"6",
       "artistname":"Henry McCullough Stage",
       "eventid":"",
       "eventname":""
    },
    "17":{
       "gigid":"264",
       "artist_id":"141",
       "gig_date":"2021-08-14 17:15:00",
       "gigname":"Cormac Neeson",
       "artistname":"Cormac Neeson",
       "profileimgURL":"",
       "venue_id":"",
       "stage_id":"3",
       "venuename":"",
       "festivalid":"1",
       "festivalname":"Stendhal Festival",
       "stageid":"3",
       "artistname":"Air Stage",
       "eventid":"",
       "eventname":""
    },
    "18":{
       "gigid":"270",
       "artist_id":"146",
       "gig_date":"2021-08-14 17:15:00",
       "gigname":"Mary Coughlan",
       "artistname":"Mary Coughlan",
       "profileimgURL":"",
       "venue_id":"",
       "stage_id":"1",
       "venuename":"",
       "festivalid":"1",
       "festivalname":"Stendhal Festival",
       "stageid":"1",
       "artistname":"Stevie Martin Stage",
       "eventid":"",
       "eventname":""
    },
    "19":{
       "gigid":"275",
       "artist_id":"151",
       "gig_date":"2021-08-14 16:30:00",
       "gigname":"The Craic Inn",
       "artistname":"The Craic Inn",
       "profileimgURL":"",
       "venue_id":"",
       "stage_id":"5",
       "venuename":"",
       "festivalid":"1",
       "festivalname":"Stendhal Festival",
       "stageid":"5",
       "artistname":"Wooly Woodland Stage",
       "eventid":"",
       "eventname":""
    },
    "20":{
       "gigid":"259",
       "artist_id":"136",
       "gig_date":"2021-08-14 16:25:00",
       "gigname":"ROE",
       "artistname":"ROE",
       "profileimgURL":"",
       "venue_id":"",
       "stage_id":"2",
       "venuename":"",
       "festivalid":"1",
       "festivalname":"Stendhal Festival",
       "stageid":"2",
       "artistname":"Karma Valley Stage",
       "eventid":"",
       "eventname":""
    },
    "21":{
       "gigid":"281",
       "artist_id":"157",
       "gig_date":"2021-08-14 16:15:00",
       "gigname":"Linley Hamilton Band",
       "artistname":"Linley Hamilton Band",
       "profileimgURL":"",
       "venue_id":"",
       "stage_id":"6",
       "venuename":"",
       "festivalid":"1",
       "festivalname":"Stendhal Festival",
       "stageid":"6",
       "artistname":"Henry McCullough Stage",
       "eventid":"",
       "eventname":""
    },
    "22":{
       "gigid":"267",
       "artist_id":"3",
       "gig_date":"2021-08-14 15:30:00",
       "gigname":"Dani Larkin",
       "artistname":"Dani Larkin",
       "profileimgURL":"https://atsusni.com/images/artistdetailprofileimages/artistid-3.jpg",
       "venue_id":"",
       "stage_id":"1",
       "venuename":"",
       "festivalid":"1",
       "festivalname":"Stendhal Festival",
       "stageid":"1",
       "artistname":"Stevie Martin Stage",
       "eventid":"",
       "eventname":""
    },
    "23":{
       "gigid":"274",
       "artist_id":"150",
       "gig_date":"2021-08-14 14:45:00",
       "gigname":"Benjamin Amos",
       "artistname":"Benjamin Amos",
       "profileimgURL":"",
       "venue_id":"",
       "stage_id":"5",
       "venuename":"",
       "festivalid":"1",
       "festivalname":"Stendhal Festival",
       "stageid":"5",
       "artistname":"Wooly Woodland Stage",
       "eventid":"",
       "eventname":""
    },
    "24":{
       "gigid":"280",
       "artist_id":"156",
       "gig_date":"2021-08-14 14:45:00",
       "gigname":"The Ocelots",
       "artistname":"The Ocelots",
       "profileimgURL":"",
       "venue_id":"",
       "stage_id":"6",
       "venuename":"",
       "festivalid":"1",
       "festivalname":"Stendhal Festival",
       "stageid":"6",
       "artistname":"Henry McCullough Stage",
       "eventid":"",
       "eventname":""
    },
    "25":{
       "gigid":"263",
       "artist_id":"140",
       "gig_date":"2021-08-14 14:00:00",
       "gigname":"Rosborough",
       "artistname":"Rosborough",
       "profileimgURL":"",
       "venue_id":"",
       "stage_id":"3",
       "venuename":"",
       "festivalid":"1",
       "festivalname":"Stendhal Festival",
       "stageid":"3",
       "artistname":"Air Stage",
       "eventid":"",
       "eventname":""
    }
 }
```

**PHP Code - without data**

```
<div id="HistoricalGigs" class="tabcontent">
<br><br>

<?php
  if (true) { 
   
  $currentboxid = 0;
  $rows = [];
  foreach ($rows as $row) {
        
        $gigdate =  $row["gig_date"];
        $ukgigdate = date("l, d F Y - g:i A", strtotime($gigdate));
        $eventid = $row["eventid"];
        $currentboxid = $currentboxid + 1
        
        ?>
        <div id="gigboxforanimate<?php echo $currentboxid;?>" class="hidden">
        <?php if ($eventid > 0) { ?>
        <p class="gigbox">
        <?php } else if ($row["festivalid"] > 0){?>
        <p class="gigboxfestival">
        <?php } else echo '<p class="gigboxblue">';?>   
        <a href="/gigdetail.php?gigid=<?php echo $row["gigid"];?>" class="gigdatesstyled"><?php echo $ukgigdate;?></a> <br><br>
        
        <strong><a href="/gigdetail.php?gigid=<?php echo $row["gigid"];?>" class="gignamesstyled"><?php echo $row["gigname"];?></a></strong><br><br>
    
    <?php   
         if (empty($row["profileimgURL"])) { 
         
    $profilepic = '/images/artistdetailprofileimages/placeholder.svg';
    $artistname = $row["artistname"];

echo '<a href="/gigdetail.php?gigid='.$row["gigid"].'"> <img srcset="'.$profilepic.' 200w,  
                   '.$profilepic.' 500w"
               sizes="(max-width: 500px) 200px,
                      500px"
               src="'.$profilepic.'" alt="'.$artistname.'"></a><br><br>';
               
} else {
    
    $profilepic = $row["profileimgURL"];
    $artistname = $row["artistname"];

echo '<a href="/gigdetail.php?gigid='.$row["gigid"].'"> <img srcset="'.$profilepic.' 250w,  
                   '.$profilepic.' 500w"
               sizes="(max-width: 500px) 250px,
                      500px"
               src="'.$profilepic.'" alt="'.$artistname.'"></a><br><br>';

}   
        ?>
        

                
        <a href="/artistdetail.php?artistid=<?php echo $row["artist_id"];?>" class="artiststyled"><?php echo $row["artistname"]??'';?></a><br>
        
        <?php if ($row["venue_id"] > 0){?>

        <a href="/venuedetail.php?venueid=<?php echo $row["venue_id"];?>" class="venuestyled"><?php echo $row["venuename"]??''. "<br>";?></a>
        
        <?php } else if ($row["festivalid"] > 0){?>
        
        <a href="/festivaldetail.php?festivalid=<?php echo $row["festivalid"];?>" class="festivalstyled"><?php echo $row["festivalname"]. "<br>";?></a>
        
        <?php } else echo '';?>     
    
    <?php if ($eventid > 0) {
        ?>
        <br><strong>Played as a part of: <a href="/eventdetail.php?eventid=<?php echo $eventid;?>" class="eventnamessmallstyled"><?php echo $row["eventname"]??'';?></a></strong><?php 
        } else echo '' ?>
        
        <?php if ($row["stageid"] > 0){?>
        
        <br><br><strong>Played on stage: <a href="/stagedetail.php?stageid=<?php echo $row["stageid"];?>" class="festivalnamessmallstyled"><?php echo $row["stagename"]??'';?></a></strong><br>
        
        <?php } else echo '';?>
                
        </p><br>
        <center>.- - ... ..- ... -. .. .-.-.- -.-. --- --</center><br>
        </div>

        <script>

$(function() {
    
    $('#gigboxforanimate<?php echo $currentboxid; ?>').slideDown(1000);
    
});
</script>
        
        <?php 
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}

?>
</div>
```